# issue with ansible slack module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to use the slack module with ansible 2.1.  I created a slack api token (recreated it today to test) and used it inside a role's task.  However, when the task gets called, I get the error copied below:

```
- name: Send notification message via Slack all options
  local_action:
    module: slack
    token: "test-12121212121-12121212121-121212121-thiswasgeneratedtoday"
    msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} completed"
    channel: "#valid-slack-channel-name"
    username: "valid-slack-user-name"
   # parse: 'none'
```

**error**

```
fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"attachments": null, "channel": "#slack-channel-test", "color": "normal", "domain": null, "icon_emoji": null, "icon_url": "http://www.ansible.com/favicon.ico", "link_names": 1, "msg": "localhost completed", "parse": null, "token": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", "username": "valid-user", "validate_certs": true}, "module_name": "slack"}, "msg": "Slack has updated its webhook API.  You need to specify a token of the form XXXX/YYYY/ZZZZ in your playbook"}
```

Once I added the domain to the task, I get the error copied below:

```
"msg": " failed to send payload={\"username\": \"valid-slack-user-name\", \"text\": \"localhost completed\", \"link_names\": 1, \"channel\": \"#valid-slack-channel-name\", \"icon_url\": \"http://www.ansible.com/favicon.ico\"} to https://hooks.slack.com/services/[obscured]: HTTP Error 404: Not Found"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you specify token in correct format.
This works fine for me in Ansible 2.1.2.0:

```
- local_action:
    module: slack
    token: "QWERTYUIO/ASDFGHJKL/klwerisSDFBhwrekjhskdjfd"
    msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} completed"
    channel: "@mynickname"
```

Comment: thank - the test token I get from slack has dashes - not slashes.

Comment: @alihaider are you sure that you request token for [incoming webhook](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks)? It has `https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` format.

Comment: I was using the oauth token and had to use the webhook integration URL instead.  Will test and update here - spaciba

Comment: Yes, as per @Konstantin's suggestion, I had to use the token from the webhooks integration URL (as opposed to using an oauth token).